# Robotium ListView with Buttons, can't click on the buttons in the list

Tags: robotium

I have a dragablelistview with a title and imagebuttons for each item to delete that item. 
How do I click on the imageview?

clickInList(int , int) does not work (unless i am doing it wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

Try 
clickOnText(String) or clickOnImage(int) clickOnImageButton(int) instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to obtain the view of the list item, something like this :

```
//get the list view
ListView myList = (ListView)solo.getView(R.id.list);
//get the list element at the position you want
View listElement = myLyst.getChildAt(position);
//click on imageView inside that list element
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(listEelement.findViewById(R.id.image_button)));
```